# Python continue apparently not returning control to while loop

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a while loop based on a MySQLdb cursor in which I need to move to the next iteration based on some conditions in an if statement. Sanitised code looks like this:

```
    row = cur.fetchone()

    while row is not None: 
      unique_id = row[0] 
      mac = row[1] 
      url = row[2]

      location = old_path + unique_id 

      os.chdir(location)
      file_count = 0
      for file in os.listdir(location): 
        if file.startswith('phone.') and file.endswith('.cfg'):
            file_count = file_count + 1

      if file_count != 1: 
        userprompt = 'Multiple phone.MAC.RANDOM.cfg files detected continue?'
        cont = query_yes_no(userprompt) # prompt user on what to do next - abort or continue
        if cont == False:
          debugmsg = 'User requested abort - aborting'
          print debugmsg
          logger.info(debugmsg)
          sys.exit()
        elif cont == True:
            debugmsg = 'Moving to next on user request'
            logger.info(debugmsg)
            continue
```

This code does not behave as expected. When run, if it hits a directory that matches the `file_count !=1` condition, the loop appears to run again without advancing to the next row. Unless I have misunderstood the use of `continue` I thought it should effectively quit that iteration of the loop and move to the next row.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure `cont` isn't something different thant True or False? E.g. None? (i.e. does your logger.info() call really log the message ?)

Comment: Maybe I'm being sensitive but I don't see why this got downvoted? :-/

Comment: @FrankSchmitt yes am sure of the value of `cont` as its set by the function `query_yes_no`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of 'continue' you need to fetch the next row:
row = cur.fetchone()

Comment: This sounds like a good solution - if I do this, presumably I will need to continue too? i.e. `cur.fetchone()` then `continue`

Comment: This worked very well thanks, using the existing code, with the addition of `cur.fetchone()` and `continue` as mentioned in my previous comment

Comment: No, you don't need 'continue' in this case. After the last statement the loop will continue anyway, i.e. execute the while expression again.

Comment: sorry I did need `continue` but this was because in my *actual* code there was more in the while loop, I just edited for brevity. But thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that `continue` will move to the next iteration.

However, you are not modifying anything in any iteration.
Your statement `row is not None`, in your `while` never changes. It's either always true or always false.

You probably want to do something like this:

```
while cur.fetchone() is not None: 
  #your code
```

Or better yet:

```
while cur.fetchone(): 
  #your code
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)